# Replacing images and db file in mobile app

Tags: android, git, sqlite

I have inherited a mobile app that is a business directory of sorts.

While the code will stay the same, I have an updated SQLite database and associated images that we want to apply to the app.

I am new to git (the original developer stored it in BitBucket) so am trying to find my way with this.

Can I just replace the files (db and jpgs) and recompile?

Thanks in advance

Steven

Comment: Was the mobile app already versioned by Git?

Comment: I believe so, the repo address mentions git

Comment: Just `git add` the files you changed, make a commit via `git commit`, then push your work out the repository.  But you should review a basic Git tutorial first.

Comment: OK great, I will, is there an add for multiple files (about 700 images)

Comment: Yes, you can add entire paths, e.g. `git add \path\to\images\*.jpg`

Comment: But typical usage of `git add` day-to-day is usually adding only a handful of files, which you can enter easily by hand.